# c# regex @"[;]+"

Tags: regex

In c#, there is a line of code such as:

```
string[] values = Regex.Split(fielddata, @"[;]+");
```

On what values does this split? I'm getting a bit confused by the mixture of literals from the @ sign and what the square braces and + mean here. Any ideas?

Comment: That looks like a regex that matches one or more consecutive semicolons.

Comment: @Asad - thank you so much for confirming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ is a verbatim string literal, meaning you don't have to escape special characters. As Asad already said, it splits on one or more consecutive semicolon, where + stands for 1 or more (regex grammar)

Here's a runnable example: http://ideone.com/whLqUe

```
        string input = "a;b; ;c;;;d";
        string[] values = Regex.Split(input, @";+");
        foreach (var value in values)
            Console.WriteLine(value);
```

outputting

```
a
b

c
d
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is a good tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

`[...]` is a character class matching any single character inside the square brackets. In this case it is redundant, just writing `@";+"` would mean exactly the same.

`+` repeats the previous character or pattern 1 or more times.

So this splits on consecutive `;` (as many as possible).

The verbatim string (`@"..."`) is used simply as a matter of good practice. Once you need to escape things inside regular expressions, it gets ugly if you use a normal string. Again, in this particular example, it would not make a difference to leave out the `@`. But it's something worth getting used to.

Answer (score 1):

Those brackets are unnecessary. That regex is equivalent to the following:

```
string[] values = Regex.Split(fielddata, @";+");
```

It'll split on any amount of semi-colons, so that `"1;2;;3;;4;;;5;;6;7"` would return an array:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Answer (score 1):

The split method will split fielddata on 1 or more semi colons.  The @ symbol means that you do not have to escape characters and the string is verbatim what is between the double quotes.

if `fielddata = "a;b;c;;d;e;;;f"`
then

```
values = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```